# How is OpenMP directives handled by compiler

Tags: c, openmp, directive

1. I was wondering how OpenMP
   directives are handled by compiler,
   such as gcc?
2. For example, in this code

   ```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      #pragma omp parallel  
      printf("Hello, world.\n");
      return 0;
    }
   ```

   Does preprocessor of gcc modify the C code by
   replacing the OpenMP directive with
   some other code?

   What is the code like after
   preprocessing and right before being
   assembled?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2):

You can do a web search and find papers discussing this topic. I hate to give links because they constantly change, but in this case it is the easiest way to answer your question. Here are two that you can look at:

[The Thing from another World (or: How do OpenMP Compilers Work? Part 1), by Michael Klemm](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2010/03/04/the-thing-from-another-world-or-how-do-openmp-compilers-work-part-1/)

[How OpenMP is Compiled, by Barbara Chapman](https://iwomp.zih.tu-dresden.de/downloads/OpenMP-compilation.pdf)

Hopefully this will answer your question.

Comment: You were right indeed. The links are dead, but I was able to find them by googling the names. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know first hand, but it's very unlikely that GCC (or any compiler) will preprocess the code when it encounters those pragmas. Most likely, GCC will just flag that block internally and then generate the appropriate native code. There is no intermediate C++ code.

Comment: Thanks! Note that only C not C++ code here. By native code, do you mean binary machine code in the instruction set of the CPU?

Comment: @Tim. Yes, that's what I meant.