# How differently are Compiler directives and preprocessor directives handled by compiler

Tags: c, gcc

In C, I was wondering how differently compiler directives and preprocessor directives are handled/implemented  by compiler such as GCC? Thanks!

By compiler directives, they are as in:

> OpenMP (Open Multi-Processing) is an
>   application programming interface
>   (API) that supports multi-platform
>   shared memory multiprocessing
>   programming in C, C++, and Fortran on
>   many architectures, including Unix and
>   Microsoft Windows platforms. It
>   consists of a set of **compiler directives**, library routines, and
>   environment variables that influence
>   run-time behavior.

Comment: The preprocessor is actually standardized by the C standard, so you should have a good idea what it does by reading that one. As for "compiler directives", please explain what you mean by that and consult your compiler's documentation. [After your edit:] Is this a question about C or about OpenMP?

Comment: @delnan: Just gave an example.

Comment: @Kerrek: Just gave an example.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348251/how-is-openmp-directives-handled-by-compiler)? Do you mean to ask about `#pragma`s?

Comment: @Kerrek: No. That is specific for OpenMP, while this is general. I guess #pragma is just one example of compiler directives? Are there other compiler directives?

Comment: @Tim: There are some #pragmas regarding _[packing](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure_002dPacking-Pragmas.html)_; perhaps those may be of interest. Consult your GCC manual for details.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler handles preprocessor directives as specified  [in **C99**](http://wwwold.dkuug.dk/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n869/n869.pdf.gz) section 6.10.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers don't handle preprocessor directives; preprocessors do that. Once the preprocessor is done, it gives its output to the compiler, which can interpret compiler directives (like `#pragma`s) as it sees fit.

Comment: Thanks! How does GCC handles compiler directives?

Comment: See [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc). You may be interested in `-fopenmp`.

Comment: @Tim -- gcc is open source. So instead of asking three times how gcc does something, how 'bout finding gcc and reading the sources? For a quick overview, man gcc. RFTM, guy. Question is largely meaningless, anyway, and certainly overbroad. Get a life.

Answer (score 1):

As for the preprocessor, see Pete Wilson's answer. As for the `#pragma` directive, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Compiler-specific_preprocessor_features) has this to say:

> The #pragma directive is a compiler specific directive which compiler vendors may use for their own purposes.

Comment: How does GCC implements compiler directives? Some general ideas will be fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "implement"? As it says, pragmas are vendor-specific instructions to the compiler, they can do all sorts of things. There's nothing "general" about them, they might do nothing or wipe your hard disk or make you coffee... For example, the "pack" pragma in GCC (and MSVC?) controls how aggregate `struct`s are aligned in memory, so that's "implemented" in the assembly that the compiler generates. Other pragmas disable warnings, e.g. one I've seen a few times is a using `*this` in a C++ constructor. It's "implemented" by the compiler not complaining when you say `*this`.